# Can number of states in DFA be greater than $2^n$ when language-equivalent NFA has $n$ states?

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata

As title says, can the number of states in DFA be greater than $2^n$ when language-equivalent NFA has $n$ states - that is if the NFA recognizes the same language as the DFA and has $n$ states, can DFA have more than $2^n$ states?

I think it is, and this is trivially. However Wikipedia seeems to write that it is not possible to have more than $2^n$ states. So comes the question.

Comment: The person asking you the question probably means pairs $(A, f(A))$ where $f$ is the powerset construction for determinising NFA.

Comment: The $2^n$ bound is for the minimal DFA. Of course you can increase the size arbitrarily by duplicating the set of states.

Comment: Where does Wikipedia say that?  Please provide a link and a quote.  I suspect you are misunderstanding Wikipedia and your question is based on a faulty premise and a too-fast reading of what Wikipedia actually says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it surely **can**, but it needs not. Using the [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) you can convert any $n$-state NFA into a DFA with at most $2^n$ states.

Comment: @Juho My guess is the OP copied the question wrong.

Comment: @Juho, it should answer the question. Starting from an NFA with n states, The MINIMAL equivalent DFA will have at most $2^n$, but an arbitrary DFA that accepts the same language may have more (redundant, useless) states.